# Find $\frac{dF(x)}{dx}$ Where $F(x)=\int_{2^x}^{3+x^3}\cos t^2\;dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

Find $\frac{dF(x)}{dx}$ Where$$F(x)=\int_{2^x}^{3+x^3}\cos t^2\;dt$$

I'm not entirely sure about how to do this question having only done basic integrals with $R$ values for $a,b$.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: $$F(x) = \int_{2^x}^{3+x^3}C^2\;dt =\int_{0}^{3+x^3}C^2\;dt + \int_{2^x}^{0}C^2 \;dt$$

$$\dfrac{dF(x)}{dx} = \dfrac{d}{d(3+x^3)}\left(\int_{0}^{3+x^3}C^2\;dt \right)\dfrac{d(3+x^3)}{dx} + \dfrac{d}{d(2^x)}\left(\int_{2^x}^{0}C^2 \;dt\right) \dfrac{d( 2^x)}{dx}$$

Can you solve this ?

Comment: Do you know [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)?

Comment: @A---B Would I just sub in $3+x^3$ into $C^2$, and then find the derivative of $3+x^3$ and do the same to the other side?

Comment: @MANMAID I don't quite remember it. This is for a higher year calculus course and we got some practice problems to refresh our memory and I have forgotten all about it. Time to watch some videos and read up that wiki I guess haha

Comment: @HelloMellow "read up that wiki I guess"-- you must... this is straight forward if you know that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Let $f(t) = \cos t^2$

Notice if

$\int \cos t^2 dt = g(x)$ then
$\int_{2^x}^{3+x^3} \cos t^2 dt = g(3+x^3) - g(2^x)$

Then your derivative is

$(3+x^3)'f(3 + x^3) - (2^x)'f(2^x)$

Using the chain rule.

Comment: Very nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use $\frac{d}{dx}(\int_{f(x)}^{g(x)}h(t)dt)=h(g(x))g'(x)-h(f(x))f'(x)$